# Devise: update (edit) User via Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, devise

I already successfully made sign-in/sign-up to work via Ajax in Devise (following an article in blog post). But I can't make it to work with ajax **update** action. I want a user to be able to edit his settings via ajax, receiving proper JSON response.

So tried to copy **update** method from Devise and I edited it to send back proper JSON response:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def update
    self.resource = resource_class.to_adapter.get!(send(:"current_#{resource_name}").to_key)
    prev_unconfirmed_email = resource.unconfirmed_email if resource.respond_to?(:unconfirmed_email)

    if update_resource(resource, account_update_params) # <<< PROBLEM IS HERE
      sign_in resource_name, self.resource, :bypass => true
      render json: resource, status: :ok
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      render json: resource, status: :not_acceptable
    end
  end
end
```

This gives me an error:

```
undefined local variable or method "account_update_params"
```

**account_update_params** is a protected method in one of Devise's files - if I copy+paste it to my child class:

```
  def account_update_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:account_update)
  end
```

it gives me next error

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer not found
```

So it looks like I'm going a wrong way.

Comment: please try `gem 'devise', github: 'plataformatec/devise', branch: 'rails4'`

Comment: but I'm still on Rails 3, is it ok?

Comment: or try `before_filter :account_update_params, if: :devise_controller?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by changing

```
if update_resource(resource, account_update_params)
```

to this

```
if resource.update_without_password(params[resource_name])
```